# C - Implementing Queue of Char * Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, queue

I want to implement a queue which holds 10 elements of `char *` array. I searched on the internet but couldn't find enough solutions.
I have a `char` array:

```
char str[50]: 
char *arr[5];
```

And the user enters some string with backspace character e.g "Hello I am computer". The string is in `str[]` array. I token them with `strtok()` function and assign it to the `arr[]`.Then it becomes:

```
//arr[0] = "Hello"
//arr[1] = "I"
//arr[2] = "am"
//arr[3] = "computer"
```

It is ok until now, I am doing it correctly.

Now my question is how to hold this whole `arr` array in queue's first node or element. There are lots of examples about queue that holding `int` values and they are easy to understand, but I couldn't do the `char *` version.

Comment: can you use structs? how is your queue being implemented? (arrays? lists? etc.)

Comment: Just replace `int` with `char *`? The queue itself should not differ at all.

Comment: Should I use  **char**(malloc)**  instead of **int*(malloc)**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question you need to implement a queue of type string.

You can do it as you do with any other queue.But instead of `int` it would of type `char*` you would also need to pass length of the word so you could dereference that many number of `char` starting from the char pointer till length of the word.

```
void Enqueue(char* x, int len)
{
    // if empty 
        front = rear = 0; 
    // else 
        rear = (rear+1);
    char ch[100];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
        ch[i] = *(x+i);
    }
    Arr[rear] = ch;
}
```

Comment: I will clear the array and next input will be stored in the queue's second node.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a queue of string.Am I right?

Comment: Yes, totally. I want to store the string of char * array in queue. In each time I will clear the string and put the inputs into next node.

Comment: Can't you simply use c++ std::string , or is it some homework it would be much easier to implement this in c++.Anyways have you done something till now it would be much easier to solve your problem if you post your implementation of the queue(if you have).

Comment: It can be easier but I'm working on C right now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to be careful when saving an address to a variable that you want to use later. You have to ensure that the address hold by the pointer is still valid when you read from it:

```
int main()
{
   char str[] = "Hello I am computer";   // "Hello I am computer" is stored on the stack
   AddStringToQueue(str[0]);   
}
// str could be overwritten by another function who allocates local variables
```

As you said in the comment you should use `void* malloc(sizeof("Hello I am computer"))` which return the start pointer of your allocated memory.

The other thing is why you want to store the string as tokens? Wouldn't it be easier to store the whole string (`"Hello I am computer"`) and use the first character as your start address for the string? If you need it as tokens you maybe can call strtok() after you read out the queue.

Let me make an example:

```
#define QUEUE_MAX 10
int QueuePos = 0;
char* Queue[QUEUE_MAX];
memset(Queue, NULL, sizeof(Queue));

// call AddStringToQueue("Hello I am computer"); anywhere

void AddStringToQueue(char* string)
{
   char* ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(string));
   memcpy(ptr, string, sizeof(string));
   Queue[QueuePos++] = ptr;
   if (QueuePos == QUEUE_MAX) QueuePos = 0;  // overwrites Queue if max. is reached
}
```

I am not sure if you mean this.

Hope it helps.

PS: I didn't compiled this so i am not sure if it works, it should just be an example.